# רש״י's use of the קל וחומר after it's been discredited (שבת כו ע״ב)‎

Tags: clothing, rashi, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, maseches-shabbos

[The *Bavli*, *Shabas* 26 *amud* 2](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=175), derives from some wording in *Vayikra* that a three-finger-by-three-finger piece of wool or linen fabric can become [*tame*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tumah_and_taharah).

- It then proposes that the verse teaches us only that a three-**hand**-by-three-**hand** piece of wool or linen fabric can become *tame* [and that we have no source for a three-finger-by-three-finger piece].

  - It counters that we need no verse to teach us about a three-hand-by-three-hand piece, as the latter can be derived from a [*kal vachomer*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_fortiori_argument): since warp and weft threads (of wool or linen) can become *tame*, of course a three-hand-by-three-hand piece of wool or linen fabric can.

    - It then proposes that the same *kal vachomer* be used to prove that a three-finger-by-three-finger piece of wool or linen fabric can become *tame*, so the wording of the verse is not needed to teach that.

      - It replies that the *kal vachomer* cannot be used to prove that a three-finger-by-three-finger piece of wool or linen fabric can become *tame*, as such a piece of fabric is not necessarily more significant than warp and weft threads.
- It then proposes that the verse teaches us that a three-hand-by-three-hand piece of fabric, **not** of wool or linen, can become *tame*.

On that last point, *Rashi* comments: "And a three-finger-by-three-finger piece of wool or linen fabric can become *tame* by a *kal vachomer*." (And a later bit of *Rashi*, s.v. "ואימא כי אמעיט", clarifies that the *kal vachomer* is from the fact that warp and weft threads can become *tame*.)

The *Tosafos* commentary asks the obvious question: "This is not brilliant. After all, we said [that the *kal vachomer* cannot be used for a three-finger-by-three-finger piece of wool or linen fabric, as such a piece is not necessarily more significant than warp and weft threads]!" It offers no answer to this question on *Rashi*. Does anyone?

Comment: Perhaps Rashi holds that שלש על שלש (*etzba'os*) of wool or linen is more significant for wealthy people than שלשה על שלשה (*t'fachim*) of other fabrics. If so, the *kal vachomer* might become viable again, since the *limud* regarding other fabrics would preempt the earlier rejection of the *kal vachomer*.

Comment: @Fred, the rejected _kal vachomer_ is also to wool or linen. Did you mean that this is a different _kal vachomer_, one not from warp and weft but from שלשה על שלשה of other fabrics? That would be a viable explanation of _Rashi_ AFAICT except that (a) it's clearly not how _Tosafos_ read _Rashi_ and (b) _Rashi_ s.v. "ואימא כי אמעיט" clearly says the proposed _kal vachomer_ is from warp and weft. Lemme edit the question....

Comment: "*Did you mean that this is a different kal vachomer...?*" No, though that was my first thought (the problem is, though, that that doesn't seem to be a real *kal vachomer* since there is an element in other fabrics that's more obvious - namely, שלשה על שלשה).| My point was that, once the standard for what can become *tamei* is lowered (to include other fabrics), the original rejection of the *kal vachomer* might become moot (assuming that שלש על שלש of wool is more important to wealthy people than is שלשה על שלשה of other fabrics - but that's a question of *m'tzi'us* so I don't know for sure).